# Any .NET Winforms control which look like this QT's QPushButton?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

Is someone know any .NET Winform control which look like this button control?

QPushButton:
http://zetcode.com/gui/csharpqyoto/layoutmanagement/

Comment: WPF allows you to do wild things with the UI. Sky and one's imagination is the limit

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here.  You aren't specific about exactly which part of the platform you are using, but if using Winforms, you can certainly customize the buttons to some extent.

If you are using WPF, you can pretty much make it look exactly like you want in XAML.  Check out Expression Blend.

As @Dimitri put it, the sky is the limit, but you may need to do the leg work.

Comment: Sorry.
I'm talking about Winforms, not WPF

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom controls according your need and have its reference added to your project. you will have it added to your toolbox that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to a button that is located on this example form:

[image]

We currently finishing our own application that has rather similar looking buttons. We did this by using a third party component. Steps are:

1. We purchased [DevExpress.com's WinForms library](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/).
2. We developed our own [DevExpress Skin](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/Features_PaintStyles.xml) (with the help of an external screen design guy)

This was a bit of a work and some amount of money but the results look pretty neat.